# Dynamically generating Rules from the content of an (Action a)

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm currently testing porting our build system from make to shake and have hit a roadblock:

Given the following project structure:

```
static/a.js
static/b.coffee

build/a.js
build/b.js
```

That is, various input extensions map to identical output extensions, so a straightforward `"build//*.js" %>` rule isn't going to work.

I wanted to avoid using priority if possible, and writing an ad-hoc build rule that checks for the existence of either possible input felt clunky (especially since this situation occurs with other filetypes as well), so I wrote the following:

```
data StaticFileMapping a = StaticFileMapping String String (FilePath -> FilePath -> Action a)

staticInputs :: FilePath -> StaticFileMapping a -> Action [FilePath]
staticInputs dir (StaticFileMapping iExt _ _) = (findFiles (dir </> "static") [iExt])

staticInputToOutput :: StaticFileMapping a -> FilePath -> FilePath
staticInputToOutput (StaticFileMapping _ oExt _) = (remapDir ["build"]) . (-<.> oExt)

staticTargets :: FilePath -> StaticFileMapping a -> Action [FilePath]
staticTargets dir sfm = (map $ staticInputToOutput sfm) <$> staticInputs dir sfm

rules :: FilePath -> StaticFileMapping a -> Rules ()
rules dir sfm@(StaticFileMapping _ _ process) = join $ mconcat . (map buildInputRule) <$> staticInputs dir sfm
    where buildInputRule :: FilePath -> Rules ()
          buildInputRule input = (staticInputToOutput sfm input) %> (process input)
```

That way I can define a mapping for each input type (`.coffee -> .js`, `.svg -> .png`) and so on, with only a tiny amount of code implementing the transformation for each. And it almost works.

But it seems impossible to go from `(Action a)` to `Rules _` without throwing the value inside the `Action` away first, as far as I can tell.

Is there a function with type `(Action a) -> (a -> Rules ()) -> Rules ()` or `(Action a) -> (Rules a)`? Can I implement either one myself, or do I need to modify the library's code?

Or is this entire approach hare-brained and I should take some other route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, using `priority` would not work, as that picks a rule statically then runs it - it doesn't backtrack. It's also important that Shake doesn't run any `Action` operations to produce `Rules` (as per the two functions you propose) since the `Action` might call `need` on a `Rule` that it itself defines, or is defined by another action rule, thus making the ordering of those `Action` calls visible. You could add `IO (Rules ()) -> Rules ()`, which might be enough for what you are thinking of (directory listing), but it isn't currently exposed (I have an internal function that does exactly that).

To give a few example approaches it's useful to define plausible commands to convert `.js`/`.coffee` files:

```
cmdCoffee :: FilePath -> FilePath -> Action ()
cmdCoffee src out = do
    need [src]
    cmd "coffee-script-convertor" [src] [out]

cmdJavascript :: FilePath -> FilePath -> Action ()
cmdJavascript = copyFile'
```

**Approach 1: Use `doesFileExist`**

This would be my standard approach, writing something like:

```
"build/*.js" %> \out -> do
    let srcJs = "static" </> dropDirectory1 out
    let srcCf = srcJs -<.> "coffee"
    b <- doesFileExist srcCf
    if b then cmdCoffee srcCf out else cmdJavascript srcJs out
```

This accurately captures the dependency that if the user adds a `.coffee` file in the directory then the rule should be rerun. You could imagine sugaring up the `doesFileExist` if this is a common pattern for you. You could even drive it from you list of `StaticFileMapping` structures (do a `group` on the `oExt` field to add one rule per `oExt` than calls `doesFileExists` on each `iExt` in turn). An advantage of this approach is that if you do `shake build/out.js` it doesn't need to do a directory listing, although likely that cost is negligible.

**Approach 2: List the files *before* calling `shake`**

Instead of writing `main = shakeArgs ...` do:

```
import System.Directory.Extra(listFilesRecursive) -- from the "extra" package

main = do
    files <- listFilesRecursive "static"
    shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
        forM_ files $ \src -> case takeExtension src of
            ".js" -> do
                 let out = "build" </> takeDirectory1 src
                 want [out]
                 out %> \_ -> cmdJavascript src out
            -- rules for all other types you care about
            _ -> return ()
```

Here you operate in IO to get the list of files, then can add rules by referring to that previously captured value. Adding `rulesIO :: IO (Rules ()) -> Rules ()` would allow you to list the files inside `shakeArgs`.

**Approach 3: List the files *inside* the rules**

You can define a mapping between file names and outputs, driven from the directory listing:

```
buildJs :: Action (Map FilePath (Action ()))
buildJs = do
    js <- getDirectoryFiles "static" ["*.js"]
    cf <- getDirectoryFiles "static" ["*.coffee"]
    return $ Map.fromList $
        [("build" </> j, cmdJavascript ("static" </> j) ("build" </> j)) | j <- js] ++
        [("build" </> c, cmdCoffee ("static" </> c) ("")) | c <- cf]
```

Then lift that into a set of rules:

```
action $ do
    mpJs <- buildJs
    need $ Map.keys mpJs
"//*.js" %> \out -> do
    mpJs <- buildJs
    mpJs Map.! out
```

However, that recomputes the directory listing for every file we build, so we should cache it and make sure it's only computed once:

```
mpJs <- newCache $ \() -> buildJs
action $ do
    mpJs <- mpJs ()
    need $ Map.keys mpJs
"//*.js" %> \out -> do
    mpJs <- mpJs ()
    mpJs Map.! out
```

This solution is probably closest to your original approach, but I find it the most complex.

Comment: Silly me, I tried approach 1 first, and felt it was too clunky, so I went and generalized with a different technique, not realizing I could generalize this one.

I will try that.